# how can i resolve this error while installing web3

Tags: python, web3py

y install' for lru-dict, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for websockets, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for bitarray, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for cytoolz, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for parsimonious, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for varint, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: cytoolz, six, eth-utils, varint, rlp, pycryptodome, parsimonious, netaddr, multidict, hexbytes, frozenlist, eth-keys, base58, yarl, pyrsistent, multiaddr, eth-rlp, eth-keyfile, eth-abi, bitarray, attrs, async-timeout, aiosignal, websockets, pywin32, protobuf, lru-dict, jsonschema, ipfshttpclient, eth-account, aiohttp, web3
Running setup.py install for cytoolz ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1x2juewd\cytoolz_d8cc48a9187a4f34bf96c2d682dda0ae\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1x2juewd\cytoolz_d8cc48a9187a4f34bf96c2d682dda0ae\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9zksksgh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\cytoolz'
cwd: C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1x2juewd\cytoolz_d8cc48a9187a4f34bf96c2d682dda0ae
Complete output (53 lines):
[1/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/utils.pyx
[2/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/dicttoolz.pyx
[3/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/functoolz.pyx
[4/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/itertoolz.pyx
[5/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/recipes.pyx
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
copying cytoolz\compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
copying cytoolz_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
copying cytoolz_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
copying cytoolz_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
copying cytoolz\curried\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
copying cytoolz\curried\operator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
copying cytoolz\curried_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
copying cytoolz\functoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
copying cytoolz\recipes.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
copying cytoolz\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
copying cytoolz\cpython.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
copying cytoolz\functoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
copying cytoolz\recipes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
copying cytoolz\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
copying cytoolz_*init*_.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_dicttoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_embedded_sigs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_functoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_inspect_args.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_itertoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_none_safe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_recipes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_tlz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
copying cytoolz\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
running build_ext
building 'cytoolz.dicttoolz' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1x2juewd\cytoolz_d8cc48a9187a4f34bf96c2d682dda0ae\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1x2juewd\cytoolz_d8cc48a9187a4f34bf96c2d682dda0ae\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9zksksgh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\cytoolz' Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools. Just install the suggested packages, restart your computer, and try your program again. I can't remember exactly what are the packages to install, but the recommended few should be enough.

Comment: already did that but still still showing error

Comment: can u pls remember and exactly say what packages to install?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when using python 3.10.4. Perhaps, it's an issue with python 3.10.x versions. It worked fine for me when I used python 3.9.8.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31436620)